# Concatenação OR, AND, ORDER BY e RAND() não funcionan

Tags: mysql

Estou com o seguinte **SQL**:

```
SELECT id,titulo,slug,endereco
FROM empresas
WHERE
(categoria = ".$_GET['id']." OR categoria_2 = ".$_GET['id']."  OR categoria_3 = ".$_GET['id'].") AND (status = '1') ORDER BY chave DESC, RAND()
```

Porém ele não ordena pelo campo chave e nem funciona o Rand()

Tento manipular os **"parênteses"** aí o `status = '1'` deixa de funcionar.

Como faço para essa linha funcionar a estrutura `OR`, `AND`, `ORDER BY` e `RAND()` ?

Comment: Dê um exemplo dos dados que você tem na tabela e o resultado que quer chegar

Comment: Alguns bancos e algumas situações requerem que o cmpo do "order" esteja no "select" , se "chave" for única o order por rand() não faria sentido

Comment: @Motta Meu banco é MYSQL